# Include the URL of all hyperlinks in the document's text

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, openoffice, iwork-pages

In an effort to go "all txt" I need to find a way to make the links in `.doc` files **visible in the text,** so that the URLs will remain accessible when I paste the the text into `.txt` documents.

Will any feature in Pages, Word or OpenOffice allow me to have all the URLs' hyperlinks in a document written **beside the hyperlink, in the text**? In something like a `description[link]` pattern.

In some cases there is no description in the link, only the URL. Duplication in these cases would not be problematic.

Comment: So, to be clear, do you want plain text as output of all these operations?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

If use have basic Word documents, [`catdoc`](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/%7Evitus/software/catdoc/) will probably achieve what you need. It's easy to install on OS X through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), running `brew install catdoc`.

Let's convert this Word file.

> [image]

The output is:

```
$ catdoc test.doc 
This is   HYPERLINK "http://www.example.com"  a hyperlink .
```

As you can see, the hyperlink is placed before the description, and the field code can be removed by a simple search and replace for  `HYPERLINK` (note the spaces).